# Link to files from SDK to output folder of build instead of copying files

Tags: wpf, build, sdk, msbuild, openni

I'm investigating to OpenNI SDK ant it's wrappers for .NET. So, I created MSBuild `AfterBuild` target to copy files from SDK folder (path from environment variable) to build output folder. Now build works on each computer (even if SDK isn't installed). But in this case build is very heavy.

Is there the way to create links to this files in solution? I need build to execute only for computers with installed SDK.

Comment: you're looking for an installer, like InstallShield.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) condition to the AfterBuild target, this would prevent the AfterBuild target from running.

```
<Target Condition="Exists('$(SdkLocation)')" Name="AfterBuild">
...
</Target>
```

You could also make a [BeforeBuild target](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) containing an [Error task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx) that will cause the build to break if the SDK is not detected.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SdkLocation)')" Text="OpenNI SDK not found." />
</Target>
```

MsBuild should also be copying the SDK files to the output file if you've added [References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx) in the dependent projects.  Are you copying extra files?